# Does this situation violate Newton's third law? How?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

Consider the following setup:
We have an infinitely long current carrying wire placed on the X-axis. At some 'x' distance from it is another current carrying wire of length l and it is perpendicular to the X-axis.

[image]

We can easily find the force acting between the wires by integrating small elements on wire 1 and using the formula F = i(l×B).

I reached the final magnitude of force between wires. However, the force acting on wire 1 will be in negative X-direction but force acting on wire 2 SHOULD be perpendicular to direction of current.

So somehow here there may exist two forces but they are not equal in magnitude or direction, hence violating Newton's 3rd law.

Is this true, or is there some flaw? Please help.

Comment: It is not possible to have a finite length of wire carrying a current. You need a closed loop.

Comment: See also This question https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1614109?noredirect=1 asked today which appears to be identical